# Proof that there is no identity element

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

How can I show that there is no identity element in **Z** corresponding to '$*$' defined by $x*y = 1 + xy$

I tried replacing 1 with $x$ and then $y$ so that, $x*1 = 1 + x$ and $y*1 = 1 + y$ but I don't know if that proves anything.

Comment: I tried replacing 1 with x and then y so, x*1=1+x and y*1=1+y but i dont know if that proves anything

Comment: hint:  an identity $e$ would have to satisfy $x=x*e=1+xe$ for all $x\in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: An identity $e$ would have to satisfy $x=x*e=1+xe$ for all $x \in \Bbb Z$.

Apply this observation to $x = 0$, and see where it leads you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $e$ is the identity element for $*$. Then, $x=e*x=1+ex$ and we have $x=1+ex$, where this equality is in $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual product. Then, $x(1-e)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, this is an absurd.